# Get the value of group in regular expression in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following regular expression in Ruby:

```
\<name\>(.+)\<\/name\>
```

Within in if statement, like so:

```
if line =~ /\<name\>(.+)\<\/name\>/
```

Is there any way to get the value of the group `(.+)`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean `=~`, just a little typo there I am assuming.

Comment: you shouldn't really use Regex to parse XML or HTML. You should use a parser such as [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). If you're just going to use regex anyway, you don't need to escape the `<` and `>`. The following will work just fine, `<name>(.+)<\/name>`,

Comment: As @macek said, parsing XML or HTML with regex is very fragile and error-prone. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is what will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use regex to parse XML or HTML, use a real parser. I like Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<somecontainingtags><name>blah</name></somecontainingtags>')

# find all occurences
doc.search('//name').map {|n| n.inner_text } # => ["blah"]

# find the first occurance
doc.at('//name').inner_text # => "blah"
```

Answer (score 5):

It is in the variable `$1`